# Error:(138, 89) error: cannot find symbol variable THEME_HOLO_LIGHT

Tags: java, android

What is the problem? why i get the this error, I have try to import class but doesnt work.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqepe.png)

[i follow this guide, and here when he put the code.](https://youtu.be/qBl0EtXKQEQ?t=702)

Answer (score 0):

The theme was deprecated when the tutorial you linked to was made.
This means it was later removed, which is why you cannot find that theme.

Deprecated values are always replaced with something (which is better more often than not). So try to use a theme that isn't deprecated and was introduced as a replacement.

Comment: ok. Have you a tips to write there if i not write THEME_HOLO_LIGHT? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Use: Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert